# To find datatypes of column in a file given, to find max and min value of each column, in case of string find max, min string based on length

Tags: python, string, pandas, list, dataframe

**data of a given file:**

```
   Name     age   weight  
   John     21    78.5  
   kennedy  39    68.3
```

**expected output:**

```
col_name   dtype
Name       str    max: kennedy min: john
age        int    max: 39      min: 21
weight     float  max: 78.5    min: 68.3
```

****can anyone help me with a solution?**

***Also i tried this but don't know how to find it max, min for string, i just did for int, float***.**

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv(P1-UK-Bank-Customers.csv")

for col in df.select_dtypes([np.int8, np.int16, np.int32, np.int64, np.float]):

print('column: ', col)
print('max: ',df[col].max())
print('min: ',df[col].min())
print()**
```

Comment: Hi pooja, you need to defined `max` and `min` for string, before any one can give any answer

Comment: @DavidDR actually i want to print the max, min of a string based on its length..i don't know the logic..Help me with your solution..

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
def min_mx_dtype(x):
    return pd.Series(index=['min', 'max', 'dtype'],data=[x.min(), x.max(), x.dtype])

print(df.apply(min_mx_dtype).T.reset_index())

      index   min      max    dtype
0      Name  John  kennedy   object
1       age    21       39    int64
2  weight    68.3     78.5  float64
```

Comment: That was quiet good but can you pls give a solution with finding the max, min value of a string based on the string length..cuz the code doesn't work in case of string in the following data sample. Customer ID Name Surname Gender Age Region JobClassifi Date Joined Balance 0 100000001 Simon Walsh Male 21 England White Collar 05.Jan.15 113810.15 1 400000002 Jasmine Miller Female 34 Northern Ireland Blue Collar 06.Jan.15 36919.73 2 100000003 Liam Brown Male 46 England White Collar 07.Jan.15 101536.83

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dataframe from a list of dicts. Then print it out in whatever format you want. For strings, min and max would be equivalent to the first and last value in a list of string sorted in ascending order.

```
vals = []
for col in df.columns:
    vals.append({'col_name': col, 
                 'dtype': df[col].dtype,
                 'max': df[col].max(),
                 'min': df[col].min()})
df = pd.DataFrame(vals)
```

Output

```
  col_name    dtype      max   min
0     Name   object  kennedy  John
1      age    int64       39    21
2   weight  float64     78.5  68.3
```

Comment: That was quiet good but can you pls give a solution with finding the max, min value of a string based on the string length..cuz the code doesn't work in case of string in the following data sample.                                                                               Customer ID Name Surname Gender Age Region JobClassifi Date Joined Balance
0 100000001 Simon Walsh Male 21 England White Collar 05.Jan.15 113810.15
1 400000002 Jasmine Miller Female 34 Northern Ireland Blue Collar 06.Jan.15 36919.73
2 100000003 Liam Brown Male 46 England White Collar 07.Jan.15 101536.83